# Comments in a pem file

Tags: openssl, pem

Is there a way to put comments in a pem certificate such that openssl will ignore the comments while parsing the certificate?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Anything outside `-----BEGIN FOO-----` and `-----END FOO-----` should be ignored by OpenSSL.

This behavior is commonly used to e.g. embed an entire human-readable detailed description of the cert in the PEM file itself, so that anyone reading it can see what it encodes without having to invoke `openssl x509 ...`  on it.

Comment: I find easier to read DER encoded as human than PEM cert but maybe you speak MIIDmTCCAwKgAwIBAgIJAI9FeLH+K7wTMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGAMQs[...]

Comment: I've run into software that fails to parse a PEM if there is any text in the file preceding `-----BEGIN FOO-----` This seems to be an exception. Any idea when and where that occurs because the error messages were not helpful. Presumable the code is not using Openssl's library.

Comment: On Android 8.0 the X509 certificate factory failed to parse the file with some string ahead of `-----BEGIN ...`. String after `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` works OK ... (maybe I'm just ignorant and that factory requires already stripped input, or maybe it's one of those weird software) (in my code the error had very ugly effect of making SSL certificate pinning code to fallback down to system CA storage, instead of validating only the specific pin, so wouldn't I verify the functionality with testing, I would have there security hole...).

Comment: Similar error happens with the `ruby-saml` gem when formatting a pem with prefix / suffix comment. Does anyone know if comment in PEM is formally defined anywhere?

Comment: Yes, see RFC 1422 (part of a series from 1421 through 1424), as explained on https://serverfault.com/a/9717