# How to load certificate bundle in C#?

Tags: c#

Suppose you have bundle which contains certificates in same manner you see it in Git certs:

```
foo/bar.ca-bundle
  - cer 1
  - cer 2
  - ...
```

It is written like so:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
some base 64 1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
some base 64 2
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
some base 64 3
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

How I can load these as cert collection?

Currently `new X509Certificate2("foo/bar.ca-bundle")` loads only one certificate and doesn't throw any errors (which is a bug from my view). Does C# even support those cases out of the box?

**UPDATE**

`X509CertificateCollection.Import` doesn't working either - it will load only one certificate, silently....

Comment: Have you checked : `X509Certificate2Collection.Import` methods? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.import?view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate2collection-import(system-string-system-readonlyspan((system-char))-system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509keystorageflags) When there are more than one, you obviously can't create ONE.

Comment: @PoulBak You should maybe post that as an answer. Treating the question on a slightly higher level, handling a collection of certificates is done through the X509Certificate2Collection class, wihle X509Certificate2 handles individual certificates.

Comment: @PoulBak checked it right away - it load only ONE certificate, which is absurd.....it should at least throw errors, and not just skip tail certs entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with a collection of certificates, you have to use the `X509Certificate2Collection` object, which has a myriad of Import() functions. Some of these will only ever yield a single certificate indeed, for your use case you'll need the `ImportFromPemFile` method. That one *does* support reading multiple certificates from a single file.

```
var collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.ImportFromPemFile(@"c:\scratch\test.pem");
var certificates = collection.ToList();
```

**Net Standard 2.0 and below**

As there is no convenience method that loads multiple certificates, manually splitting up the file using code seems the way forward. I've cobbled together a piece of code in Framework 4.7 that demonstrates one way of doing this. Suggestions for improvements welcome of course...

```
var bundleContent = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\scratch\test.pem");
var certificateValues = Regex.Split(bundleContent, "(?=-----BEG)").Skip(1);
foreach (var certificateValue in certificateValues) {
    var certificateData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(certificateValue);
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateData);
    certificate.Subject.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Is it only supported in recent .net versions? Don't see it in netstd2.0

Comment: It seems to be core only (.NET 5 and upwards), indeed

Comment: I have added some code that demonstrates how to do this manually, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Simple and nice solution =) It could also contain comments, so it is probably better to strip them.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578812/comments-in-a-pem-file

Comment: Good point! The X509Certificate2 object will ignore anything outside the begin...end markers, but my original code did mess up the first part if the file started with comments. Subtle fix applied :) Obligatory note that if you know you are dealing with pem files with random comments you might need a more complete regex or a proper parser.